# Make HTML form elements appear (jQuery or JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering if a jQuery or JS library exists that does the following:

Based on what a user inputs in A01, check that value, and if that value is equal to 'x', make A01_1 visible. If not, do nothing.

```
<form id="survey">
    <fieldset>
            <label for="A01">A01</label>
            <input type="number" name="A01" id="A01" min="0" max="5" >

            <label for="A01_1">A01_1</label>
            <input type="text" name="A01_1" id="A01_1" >
```

I guess I'm looking for some sort of inline validation function that will make another element visible if it matches a specific input. I need to apply this in a number of different places so I want to make it a reusable function.

My JS skills are limited so any help (where to start etc.) is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[name=A01]').on('keyup', function() {

   var val = $.trim( this.value ),
       x = 'your_custom_value',
       id = this.id,
       target = $('label[for='+ id +'_1], input[name='+ id +'_1]');

   target.hide();

   if( val == x) {
     target.show();
   }
});
```

For reuse you can change you markup like:

```
<form id="survey">
    <fieldset>
            <label for="A01">A01</label>
            <input type="number" name="A01" id="A01" min="0" max="5" class="myinput">

            <label for="A01_1">A01_1</label>
            <input type="text" name="A01_1" id="A01_1" >

            <label for="A02">A02</label>
            <input type="number" name="A02" id="A02" min="0" max="5" class="myinput">

            <label for="A02_1">A02_1</label>
            <input type="text" name="A02_1" id="A02_1" >
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

And change ***jQuery*** like:

```
$('input.myinput').on('keyup', function() {

   var val = $.trim( this.value ),
       x = 'your_custom_value',
       id = this.id,
       target = $('label[for^='+ id +'_], input[name='+ id +'_]');

   target.hide();

   if( val == x) {
     target.show();
   }
});
```

Comment: Best solution. Thank you. I can 'understand' jQuery, just haven't had enough time to learn much. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkField(field) 
{
    if(field.value == 'VALUE')
        document.getElementById('A01_1').style.display = 'true';
}
</script>

<input type="number" name="A01" id="A01" min="0" max="5" onchange="checkField(this)">
```

Then apply the the style display:none to the element that you want to hide

Comment: Ah thanks, I think I understand that. I'll try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

try this:

HTML:

```
<form id="survey">
    <fieldset>
            <label for="A01">A01</label>
            <input data-relation="a01check" type="number" class="checkerinput" name="A01" id="A01" min="0" max="5" >

            <label class="noshow a01check" for="A01_1">A01_1</label>
            <input class="noshow a01check" type="text" name="A01_1" id="A01_1" >
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS:

```
(function(undefined) {

    var equalCheck = 3, $form = $('#survey');

    $form.find('input.checkerinput').bind('keyup change', function(event) {

        var value = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        if (!isNaN(value) && value == equalCheck){
            var relation = $(this).data('relation');
            if (relation != undefined) {
                $form.find('.' + relation).removeClass('noshow');
            }
        }
    });

})();​
    ​
```

CSS:

```
.noshow{
    display:none;
}​
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/VFDYG/)